# Push Plugin Cordova IOS GCM not firing register event / not showing device token

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

My Xcode version is 6.3.2.. I'am building a ionic application and have installed  phonegap-plugin-push 1.8.4 on my cordova-ios 4.1.1...

My code works perfectly on android but on ios i'am not able to register the device token nor do i see any errors in the xcode console.. I have followed all the steps and installed the development push notification certificate and is enabled as well

Have selected team in the general section on xcode.. Below is my code

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform,$cordovaVibration,$state,$ionicPopup) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      var push = PushNotification.init({

    ios: {
        senderID: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
        alert: "true",
        badge: "true",
        sound: "true",
        gcmSandbox: "true"
    },

});

push.on('registration', function(data) {
    alert(data.registrationId);
    window.localStorage['gcm_token'] = data.registrationId;
});

push.on('notification', function(data) {
    // data.message,
    // data.title,
    // data.count,
    // data.sound,
    // data.image,
    // data.additionalData
});

push.on('error', function(e) {
    window.localStorage['gcm_tokenn'] = e.message;
});

})
})
```

What am i missing? There are no error logs in xcode have triple checked this.. I have added the .p12 certificate in FCM... Also tested this on actual device and not simulator

Comment: You may check this related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/567) which suggested that if you build your app as development then you need to set `gcmSandbox:true`. If you build your app for production then you need to set `gcmSandbox:false`. I've seen that you have tried possible workarounds but still experiencing an error. I checked on these forums: [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/46011) and [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/842) and it seems that it's an issue from Apple APN before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i got it working.. After installing the Os :: macOS sierra 10.12.3 xcode 8.2.1 phonegap-plugin-push 1.8.4 .. i did ,

```
cordova platforms --save
cordova plugins --save 
rm -rf platforms
rm -rf plugins
ionic state restore
```

Now i get the token but have other issues , while i first run the app i get an error saying

```
the operation couldnt be completed com.google.iid error 6
```

this happens the first time.. And while i try to send notification with my php code i get success for the first time and NotRegistered after that..

Below is the php code i use

```
<?php

$apiKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$regId = 'kK4tkHyseLc:APA91bE6pozxxJC2_MZZtFC38mL5A3PRAaCekT1RLwGJcJZOHtsqtbxUZ56j-ZotoxRlCR8gEKqYbxqOQd37uSs38nJGZAZW7Nb4J6K7HuR5c46FIu05w8qsHUWlGvcQfl8fn-pY__Al';
    $url = 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $post = '{"to" : "' . $regId . '","priority":"high","content_available":true,"time_to_live":2419200,"data":{"message":"GCM Notifier:Message Success","title":"GCM Notifier:Title Success"},"notification":{"title":"GCM Notifier:Title Success","body":"GCM Notifier:Message Success","sound":"default","badge":"1"}}';

    $headers = array(
            "Authorization:key=$apiKey",
            'Content-Type:application/json'
            );

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ( curl_errno( $ch ) )
{
    echo 'GCM error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
}
curl_close( $ch );
    echo $result;
?>
```

Response ::

```
{"multicast_id":8300626558747339726,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same kind of problem earlier. By Updating the Xcode to **latest version (Xcode 8)** solved my problem. To built and integrated phonegap-plugin-push plugin 1.8.4  successfully with application need Xcode version 8 for iOS.

Also don't forget to enable Push Notifications under Capabilities in Xcode

Comment: I'll try this.. Currently Xcode 6.3.2 doesnt have the option of Push notification under capabilities. I'll update my xcode and reply,..

Comment: yep. you have to update Xcode version to 8 it will help to solve your problem.

Comment: Did you able to update your Xcode version to 8 and did it able to solve your problem?

Comment: Have just upgraded my OS from yosemite to sierra.. Now on upgrading xcode to 8.2.1 5GB .. Will take another day.. Thanks to Super Indian Internet :(

Comment: Take it easy buddy. :)

Comment: It's still the same.. Os :: macOS sierra 10.12.3 xcode 8.2.1 phonegap-plugin-push 1.8.4 .. No errors in console for the push plugin..The push.on registration method is not called.. i dont get the alert box

Comment: Delete platform and plugin folders.Then again add the platform and plugins. Then check whether there are any errors when build.

Comment: Another thing, I used ionicCloudProvider  for push notification it was worked for me. You can find the cloud configuration from their  [Ionic Cloud Doc](https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/#setup)

Comment: hi thanks.. i did the above steps mentioned in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031431/push-plugin-cordova-ios-gcm-not-firing-register-event-not-showing-device-token/42131723#42131723) but i'am still stuck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135256/discussion-between-stack-fan-and-aniket).

Comment: Hey i'am getting notifications as well now.. I'll write a blog this weekend as to what all steps i had to do and post a comment here.. I'am just pushing my build the app store to test it via test flight with the production push certificate..

Comment: Cheers! finally you got it. :)